# What is a good learning resource for TFS and how to use TFS with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

What is a good learning resource for TFS and how to use TFS with Visual Studio?
Specifically, I want to know two things.

1. Exactly what are the step-by-steps procedures of checking in code.  I know that I am required to do a code review.  So, after the code review is done by a peer, I understand that this is not enough and the original developer has to click to do something to submit the code into the TFS system.  I mean, I want to know  precisely what buttons to click on.
2. I also want to know how to use Visual Studio to look up the actual version.  How do I determine the details of what is already checked in?

Answer (score 0):

There are many blogs videos in google. If you want a full detail resource, suggest you directly take a look at our official doc here -- **[Azure DevOps Server Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/?view=azure-devops)**

A suggested learn order for your reference:

> Installation (you could skip this if your company already done this)--
>   Code -- Build&Release -- Packages-- Test-- Work-- Analysis-- Admin
>   Tool

TFS supports two types of version control: Git and Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC). One centralized and one distributed. As for which version control system should you use, you could take a look at this thread: **[Choosing the right version control for your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/?view=azure-devops)**

For your case, you could easy check the history in server side. It's called changeset in **TFVC** and commit in **Git**.

For example, when you check in your changes, they are stored on the server as a changeset. Changesets contain the history of each item in version control.

You can view a changeset to see what the exact file changes were, discover the owner's comments, find linked work items, and see if any policy warnings were triggered.

The same as Git,  actually you could find the answer for both question 1&2 in **Code** part. Hope it helps.